# How do I eliminate duplicate null checks and exception handling in controller methods?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to avoid using repetitive try/catch blocks, repetitve logging commands, and account for HTTP response codes such as 404, 200, 204, etc and minimize API method lines of code into some interface or service. In other words, make my code more DRY.

Given this code:

```
    [HttpGet()]
    [Route("Contracts/{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
    {
        try
        { 
            var results = await _service.GetContractByIdAsync(id);
            if (results == null) { return NotFound(); }             
            return Ok(results);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            _log(ex);
            return StatusCode(500); 
        }
    }
```

If I have multiple similar methods, every single line of code except

```
var results = await _service.GetContractByIdAsync(id);
```

will be repeated. How do I avoid that duplication? Maybe I'll want to change the way I handle errors later, and I don't want to have to change it in lots of places.

Comment: ...what is the question?

Comment: so you want error handling but you don't want try catch blocks, and you want conditions but you dont want if statements...?

Comment: The question is how do I implement an oft-reused pattern and not copy and paste a bunch of code.  Conditional statements (if/then) are code complexity and potentially unnecessary code paths where an interface or class could do the same.  I did not say I 'didnt want try catches' I said 'I dont want them copied and pasted a bunch of times in the API.  Thanks, sry for lack of clarity.

Comment: I understand the question. He wants the try/catch and the rest, but not to repeat them.

Comment: Which version of asp.net core? I think the error handling at least was revamped in 3.0 .

Comment: There's still really no question here. We know what you want, but you've got no code you're trying to clean up and haven't presented any issues you're having doing what you want. What is it exactly that you're looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CHALLENGE 1: try/catch**

You can add the [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) before MVC, that will execute the next middleware (including MVC) in the try/catch block:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    //...

    app.UseMyExceptionHandler();
    // ...
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

The middleware could look like this:

```cs
public class ExceptionHandlerMiddleware
{
    readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    readonly ILogger logger;

    public ExceptionHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, e);
        }
    }

    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {
        // Log the exceptions
        string result = ... cretate the response if you need it
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = 500;
        return context.Response.WriteAsync(result);
    }
}
```

And I used the extension method to add it to the app builder:

```cs
public static class MiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseMyExceptionHandler(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlerMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Now you can remove the `try/catch` from all your controller actions, because all the unhandled exceptions will be caught by the middleware.

There are also some [built-in ways](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2) of doing this that might help you.

**CHALLENGE 2: null checks for NotFound**

You can create some base controller that all your controllers will inherit from, and handle the `null` check in it:

```cs
public class BaseController : ControllerBase
{
    protected IActionResult CreateResponse(object result)
    {
        if (results == null)
            return NotFound();
        return Ok(results);
    }
}
```

and then you make all your controllers inherit from it:

```cs
[ApiController]
public class YourController : BaseController
// ...
```

And now your action method could look like this:

```cs
[HttpGet()]
[Route("Contracts/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    var results = await _service.GetContractByIdAsync(id);
    return CreateResponse(results);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define a `ResultFilterAttribute` which change all `ObjectResult`s with a null-value to a `NotFoundResult`. You can annotate your controller methods wherever it applies or even register the filter globally. See also the article [Convert Null Valued Results to 404 in asp.net-core mvc](https://www.strathweb.com/2018/10/convert-null-valued-results-to-404-in-asp-net-core-mvc/) for how and why.

The attribute would look like this (code from said article)

```
public class NotFoundResultFilterAttribute : ResultFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult && objectResult.Value == null)
        {
            context.Result = new NotFoundResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Apply it to your controller method and just return the result.

```
[HttpGet()]
[Route("Contracts/{id}")]
[NotFoundResult]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id) {
    var results = await _service.GetContractByIdAsync(id);
    return results;
}
```

Make sure your Controller is decorated with the `ApiController` attribute. I left out the try-catch-block because you can let the pipeline handle exceptions for you as well. In your `Startup.Configure` method register a lambda for `app.UseExceptionHandler(...)`.

Have a look at the Microsoft ASP.NET Core documentation - [section error handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#configure-custom-exception-handling-code) for further details.